# Secured (over https) IP address lookup API services

Tags: geolocation, ip-address, geo, ip-geolocation

Are there any geo-location api services like hostip.info that working over https

Free services are preferred

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaxMind offers geolocation services that you can use offline on your own server for free, or through their API:

- https://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity
- https://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry
- https://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip
- https://www.maxmind.com/app/api

Answer (score 2):

On some routers the firewall port `80` is blocked, ie at work, school, or at home.
So by using a HTTPS or port `433` you can scan the security or anonymity of your location.

Answer (score 1):

This company offers exactly what you are looking for, an API that works over HTTPS and for free (with some limitations when you use it for free though): http://www.IPAddressLabs.com

Comment: I agree, here is the call I use from it :

https://https-api.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/v1.7/locateip?key=demo&ip=local-ip&format=json